# C#. Multicast client-server application

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, multicast

I try to create simple console application 'Chat' using UDP protocol and multicasting. I can only send message from server to client. Server code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create object UdpClient
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();

            // IPAddress of group
            IPAddress multicastaddress = IPAddress.Parse("224.192.168.255");

            try
            {
                // Join group
                udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
            }

            // Create object IPEndPoint
            IPEndPoint remoteep = new IPEndPoint(multicastaddress, 2345);

            // Print message
            Console.WriteLine("Server is running ...\n\nEnter message: ");

            // Data in Byte []
            Byte[] buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine ());

            try
            {
                // Send data using IPEndPoint
                udpClient.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, remoteep);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString ());
            }

            // Leave the group
            udpClient.DropMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);

            // Close connection
            udpClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Net;

    namespace Client
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Create UDP client
                UdpClient client = new UdpClient();

                // Create new IPEndPoint
                IPEndPoint localEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2345);

                // Set socket options
                client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

            // Bind to IPEndPoint
            client.Client.Bind(localEp);

            // IP address
            IPAddress multicastaddress = IPAddress.Parse("224.192.168.255");

            try
            {
                // Join group
                client.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Client is running ...\n\n");

            // Receive data
            Byte[] data = client.Receive(ref localEp);
            string strData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine("Server: " + strData);

            // Leave the group
            client.DropMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);

            // Close connection
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I send message from server and receive the response from client, after this send next message and receive response from client etc.? Is it possible to implement this using `UdpClient` class and multicasting or not?

Thank you very much!